# Error trying to login: "This service cannot be accessed because your login request contained saml assertion that has already been used once"

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace, google-account

My Google Workspace account is disabled and I don't know why.

I am seeing this error:

> "Google Workspace - This service cannot be accessed because your login request contained saml assertion that has already been used once. Please try again by starting the login process from the beginning.
>
> We are unable to process your request at this time, please try again later.

I want to try and recover my documents, but it won't let me access the account.

How can I recover my documents and how can I regain access to my  account?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. We can't help with troubleshooting like questions, but we could help you with questions about Google Accounts and Google Workspace. How do you get your account? Have you signed up for a Google Workspace account by yourself at school, or work or someone else give your account?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched the web using the fragment of the error message:

> This service cannot be accessed because your login request contained saml assertion that has already been used once

This returned very few results, but two from Google Product Communities had answers from Product Experts; that is how Google calls trusted community members. As there are very few results you can do the search and see their answers by yourself.

Before doing that, there is no harm in trying the basic troubleshooting procedure when having problems with web applications. The simplest thing you could try to discard to have a problem with your Google account is the following

1. If, for any reason, you have shared your account, ask anyone that you have shared it to log out.
2. Turn off your computer and any other devices where you have used your account to log in.
3. Turn on your computer.
4. Ensure that there are no programs automatically loaded. If there are any, close them, except for the security protection (antivirus, antimalware).
5. Open Chrome in incognito mode. Ensure no extensions are loaded due to being authorized to run in incognito mode.
6. Sign in to your Google account.

If the problem, persists, having a Google Workspace account you should contact your account administrator.

Comment: If you are the Google Workspace account administrator and are not tech savvy, you should edit your question, adding more details about the type of account you have and how you get it, among other details. It might be helpful that a moderator invite you to a chatroom, but that is not done by default, so I can't assure you that it will happen.